# Promise All and Get Requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

So I'm having difficulty understanding the steps I need to take to accomplish my task. I want to get all the users "watchlists" for crypto coins (which I've done). Then return the updated data from the coinmarketcap api depending on what is saved in their watchlist. I was told I can accomplish this efficiently using Promise.all(). Would I essentially be finding/mapping the id of the coin ('bitcoin') from the mongodb watchlist and then running the get coins function with the mapped id as the coin parameter? Can anyone provide some guidance on this?

I tried to do something like this, but that didn't work. That says undefined is not a function.

```
CryptoWatchlist.find()
.then(watchlists => watchlists.map(watchlist => watchlist.id))
.then(id => Promise.all(getCoins(id)))
```

**/router/watchlist.js**

```
router.get('/watchlist', (req, res) => {
  CryptoWatchlist.find()
    .then(watchlists =>
      res.json(watchlists.map(watchlist => watchlist.serialize()))
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    });
});
```

**/api.js**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function getCoins(coin) {
  return fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/${coin}`).then(
    response => {
      return response.json();
    }
  );
}

module.exports = getCoins;
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you see?

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing the exact error I see currently is (node:17012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: undefined is not a function
(node:17012) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not too far off. This should get you on the right track:

```
const watchlistPromises = CryptoWatchlist.find()
.then(watchlists => watchlists.map(({ id }) => getCoins(id));

Promise.all(watchlistPromises).then(responses => {
    // Process responses
});
```

`responses` will be an array of getCoin promise responses that are in the same order as the watchlist array.

The idea is to map each of the coins in your list with a request to the coinmarketcap API. If your list is large you will be hitting their API hard. You may want to see if their API has an option to send multiple symbols in one request.

Comment: I did check out whether their API could get multiple symbols in one request but they can't. I believe that's why I was told to use Promise.all. Also, I tried this and I'm getting the following error: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)

Comment: @jpatel701 what version of node are you using?

Comment: Is `watchlists` an actual array - some DB's results are "array-like" but not actually arrays ... and have no `.map` method

Comment: @AndyGaskell I'm using v8.9.2

Comment: yes, from what you see ... can you confirm the `.map` method exists  - i.e, what is the output of `console.log(typeof watchlists.map)`

Comment: ok, so that's not the undefined function - read the error message fully, surely there's SOME clue as to what is undefined

Comment: @JaromandaX turns out if I console.log(typeof watchlistPromises) then I get object. I believe Promise.all takes in an array. So I guess the question is how to turn watchlistPromises into an array rather than an object. Correct me if i'm mistaken.

Comment: typeof array is object ... try Array.isArray... but you've already  determined map is a function

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise.all on resulting array of promises:

```
const promises = CryptoWatchlist.find()
  .then(watchlists => watchlists.map(watchlist => watchlist.id))
  .then(id => getCoins(id))

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the other answers, but more FP style like the original code

```
CryptoWatchlist.find()
.then(watchlists => 
    Promise.all(watchlists.map(({id}) => 
        getCoins(id)
    ))
)
```